# Spring Boot -How to change Spring Boot application jar name based on Build Environment QA or PROD

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, buildconfiguration

I am developing a spring boot application in that am using **application.yml** configuration for Three different environment **PROD/DEV/STAGE**

am using maven to build as executable jar i need help in when am building

- for  **DEV** environment the jar name should be **abc-dev.jar**
- for **PROD** environment the jar name should be **abc-PROD.jar**

am using **mvn package -Dspring.profiles.active=dev**

for building the application

how can i pick the application name dynamically and update in **pom.xml** file

Comment: You shouldn't do things like that. That basically means you are promoting an untested artifact to a different environment. You should build 1 artifact and promote that to the different stages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this in your `pom.xml`

`<packaging>jar</packaging>
 <build>
   <finalName>abc-${spring.profiles.active}</finalName>
 </build>`

This should work for Maven version >= 3

Comment: will it override artifacat id in pom??

Comment: can we do it the other way round? set the spring.application.name from the <name> tag in the pom file?